# How to seperate the selialized data in jquery

Tags: jquery

I got the form values using the `$(this).closest("#myForm").serialize();`

But here, I need to validate the values and then pass it to ajax.

i.e; my `serialize()` returns `revw_desc` & `revw_tle` drom this values I need to validate like,

```
    if(revw_tle.val().length <= 0 && revw_desc.val().length <= 0 ){
          $('.tle_error').fadeIn();
          $('.desc_error').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
            $('.tle_error').fadeOut();
            $('.desc_error').fadeOut();
            it calls AJAX..
    }
```

How should I do this..Is there anyother ways!!!..

Can anyone help me..

Comment: why don't you validate the input first and if it's correct, serialize it?

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/serializeobject

Comment: What is `revw_tle.length`? Do you mean `revw_tle.val().length` - `revw_tle.length` check the number of elements -  `revw_tle.val().length` checks the value length of said element

Comment: Because I need to pass values through Ajax only the if condition is satisfied..

Comment: `revw_tle.length` mean the length of the values.. Sorryyy... I post it wrongly :P ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if($("#myForm").find('[name=revw_tle]').val().length <= 0 && $("#myForm").find('[name=revw_tle]').val().length <= 0 ){
      $('.tle_error').fadeIn();
      $('.desc_error').fadeIn();
}
else{
        $('.tle_error').fadeOut();
        $('.desc_error').fadeOut();
        it calls AJAX..
}
```

note: you may have a problem with the id of the form if you have multiple forms

Comment: But I'm using multiple forms.. So I prefer `serialize()`..In My post I denote it as `$(this).closest("#myForm").serialize();` it only retrive the closest form values..

Comment: Okay!..I'll try.. :)

Comment: I got it.. :) Instead of `$("#myForm").find('[name=revw_tle]').val()` I gave it as using the class name of it as `$(this).closest("#myForm").find('.revw_tle').val()`... :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).closest("#myForm").find('.revw_tle').val().length <= 0 && $(this).closest("#myForm").find('.revw_desc').val().length <= 0 ){
      $('.tle_error').fadeIn();
      $('.desc_error').fadeIn();
}
else{
        $('.tle_error').fadeOut();
        $('.desc_error').fadeOut();
        it calls AJAX..
}
```

Instead of `$("#myForm").find('[name=revw_tle]')` I gave it as `$(this).closest("#myForm").find('.revw_tle')`..

I represent the closest form value..
And `.revw_tle` represents classname